# in jboss server.log file is updating only at that time of server starting after that logs are recording in start.log file

Tags: jboss

In jboss server.log file is updating only at that time of server starting. Afterwards, the logs are recording in start.log file (application log file)

We enabled the log rotation and restarted the server also. I checked standalone.xml, logging.properties, standalone.sh,log4j.xml

There we don't have any information about start.logfile?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Could you post your the `log4j.xml` and the logging configuration? It's probably easiest to use CLI and execute `/subsystem=logging:read-resource(recursive=true)` or post the appropriate portion of the `standalone.xml`.